# With a certain beacon I can know the exact position of a person?

Tags: android, geolocation, beacon

the idea is that in a room with some static beacons you can find the position (x, y) of a beacon in specific, using an android application.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not possible, because both Bluetooth beacons and mobile phones are essentially *omnidirectional transceivers*.**

This means they cannot determine the direction of where a signal came from, much less the exact position of the beacon.   All they can really do is roughly approximate the distance between the mobile device and the beacon based on the strength of the signal.  And even this can only be done if a reference signal strength (often called measured power) is transmitted by the beacon, so the receiving device knows what the expected signal strength should be at a known distance.

So even if you know approximately how far away a beacon is from a mobile device, you have no idea which direction it is in.

Comment: There is some technology that can detect its position (x, y), from a mobile application, since I have a client who asked me for an Augmented Reality application, to detect advisors in a work cafe, when focusing with the camera , the assessor must show on the camera with a marker indicating its position.

Is there any technology that helps me achieve this goal?